# Как сравнить 2 масива с обьектами и получить уникальный?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, nestjs

Есть 2 масива с обьекатми, пример:

```
  const a = [
  {
    title: '1',
    catalog: '1',
  },
  {
    title: '2',
    catalog: '2',
  },
  {
    title: '3',
    catalog: '3',
  },
];


const b = [
  {
    title: '1',
    catalog: '1',
  },
  {
    title: '2',
    catalog: '2',
  },
  {
    title: '2',
    catalog: '3',
  },
  {
    title: '3',
    catalog: '2',
  },
];
```

Массив a - это данные в базе =>  mongodb

Массив b - это данные которые я отправляю в базу => mongodb

Моя задача сравнить данные из базы с данными из файла который я отправляю, и создакть уникальный массив с данными которых нет в базе.

Есть готовое решение:

```
const filterData = (array) => {
  return array.filter((item1) => {
    const duplicate = a.find((item2) => {
      // console.log(item1.title);
      return item1.title === item2.title && item1.catalog === item2.catalog;
    });

    return !duplicate;
  });
};

const filtered = filterData(b);

await this.movieModel.insertMany(filtered);
```

Но оно очень медленное, у меня в базе 100к обьектов и я загружаю еще 100к обьектов, получается каждый обьект проверяется с другим.

Как сделать процесс максимально быстрым, чтобы создать уникальный массив обьектов и отправить сразу пачкой данные в mongodb ?

Comment: Мне кажется такую задачу можно решать на уровне БД, чтобы не гонять туда сюда данные, а отправлять сразу в Mongo, а при вставке данных сделать проверку на уникальность комбинации полей.

Comment: В том то и дело что поля в моем случае не могут быть уникальным а бд

Comment: Мне все еще нужна помощь !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел более быстрое решение, когда я добавляю в базу 100к обьектов, проверка следуйщего обьекта на дубликат сотсавляет 26 секунд, время увеличивается с добавлением новых обьектов, но если проверять скажем 20к обьектов из 100-200-300к к обьектов в базе то время составляет +- 3 секунды.

```
  async movieContentSave(data: object[]): Promise<any> {
    const find = await this.movieModel.find({});

    const mongoFind = find.map((e: any) => {
      const dataFind = {
        title: e.title,
        url: e.url,
        keyword: e.keyword,
        catalog: e.catalog,
        status: Status.DEACTIVE,
      };
      return dataFind;
    });

    const chackfields = data.map((dataObject: movieModel) => {
      const duplicate = mongoFind.find((mongoObject) => {
        return (
          dataObject.title === mongoObject.title &&
          dataObject.catalog === mongoObject.catalog
        );
      });
      if (!duplicate) {
        return dataObject;
      }
    });

    console.log(chackfields.filter(Boolean));
    // await this.movieModel.insertMany(c.filter(Boolean));

    return true;
  }
```

Если кто то может предложеть более быстрый способ с удовольствеем его рассмотрю !

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй так, вдруг поможет.Хотя я новичек в програмировании.

```
const a = [];
const b = [];
let final = [];
for (let it1 in b){
    for (let it2 in a){
        if (it1.title == it2.title && it1.catalog == it2.catalog){
            break;
        }else{
            final.push(it1);
        }
    }
}
console.log(final);
```

Comment: Ай, зачем удалил? Я ж просто полезные советы даю.

Comment: Он все равно работать не будет. Там надо начинать как минимум счётчик с 21 т.к. до 20 будет завершатся с тру. Завтра подумаю да компом.

Comment: С 2520 даже, потому что уже известно, что оно делится на все числа от 2 до 10.